# How does one download a build artifact from Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am successfully creating build artifacts in my public Github repository's Azure Pipeline:

```
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: drop
```

But after a CI build, I would like to download this artifact to my laptop and examine it. All I can find is how to make [a manual REST API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) where I need to know my build number and the artifact name.

Is it not possible to download the artifacts registered from the Azure Pipelines web interface?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Location of build artifacts has been changed. Navigate to Pipelines, Pipelines, select build run and click on link under Artifacts section. On Published artifacts page, there is link to download artifacts

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strangely, I see 1 Published item under artifacts but when I click it to download, just it doesn't work. I see the pipeline build steps and the workspace path on the Windows self-hosted machine, the artifact is there. Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to artifacts and download it there:

[image]

You would need package management license for that (first 5 are free) and appropriate permissions. top left box is the feed selector

To download a build artifact >> go to build in the build history and in the summary it will contain all the artifacts

[image]